# Google maps click to zoom into cluster of markers

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a custom mapping tool for a real estate site built on Wordpress. I want to be able to click on a category (ie. All, Retail, Outdoor, etc.) and have the map zoom/pan to show only the markers in that category. The categories are being generated in Wordpress and then added to the markers and links as data attributes. I know I need to somehow store the related markers in an array and create new bounds, but I can't seem to figure that out. I'm also not sure how to tie the category link to the new cluster of markers.

Here's my Javascript:

```
(function($) {
  /*
   *  render_map
   *
   *  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
   *
   */

  function render_map( $el ) {
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    var args = {
      zoom        : 18,
      center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
      mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      scrollwheel : false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

    map.markers = [];

    $markers.each(function(){
      add_marker( $(this), map );
    });

    center_map( map );
  }

  /*
   *  add_marker
   *
   *  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
   *
   */

  var infowindow;

  function add_marker( $marker, map ) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : latlng,
      map      : map
    });

    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() ) {
      // create info window
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content   : $marker.html()
      });

      // show info window when marker is clicked
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
        map.panTo( marker.position );
      });

      var $liProperty = $('ul.properties li').find('[data-lat="' + $marker.attr('data-lat') + '"]');

      var $liCategory = $('ul.property-categories li').find('[data-property-selector="' + $marker.attr('data-property-selector') + '"]');

      // show info window when marker is clicked
      $($liProperty).on('click', function(event) {
        infowindow.setContent( $marker.html() );
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
        map.panTo( marker.position );
      });

      // close info window when map is clicked
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        if ( infowindow ) {
          infowindow.close();
        }
      });
    }
  }



  /*
   *  center_map
   *
   *  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
   *
   */

  var bounds;

  function center_map( map ) {
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
      bounds.extend( latlng );
    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 ) {
      map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
      map.setZoom( 16 );
    } else {
      map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }
  }



  /*
   *  filter property list
   *
   */

  $('ul.property-categories li').on('click', function($marker) {
    var $catID       =  $(this).data('property-selector'),
        $targets     =  $('ul.properties li[data-property-type="' + $catID + '"]').show();

    if ($catID === 'all') {
      $('ul.properties li').show();
    } else {
      $('ul.properties li').not($targets).hide();
    }

    $('ul.property-categories li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $('ul.properties li').on('click', function() {
    $('ul.properties li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });



  /*
   *  document ready
   *
   *  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
   *
   */

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.map').each(function(){
      render_map( $(this) );
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

And here's my PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Properties Template
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Delco_Dev
 * @since Delco Dev 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

  <section class='small-hero'></section>

  <section class='properties-map'>
    <div class='properties-map__wrapper'>

      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

          <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if( have_rows('property_categories') ): ?>

        <ul class='property-categories'>

        <?php
          $firstLoop = true;
          while( have_rows('property_categories') ): the_row();
            $category = get_sub_field('property_category');
            ?>

            <li data-property-selector='<?php echo strtolower($category); ?>' <?php if ($firstLoop): ?>class='active'<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $category; ?></li>

            <?php $firstLoop = false; ?>

          <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <div class='properties__wrapper'>
        <ul class='properties'>
          <?php
            $mypages = get_pages( array(
              'child_of'    => 90,
              'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
              'sort_order'  => 'asc'
            ) );

            foreach( $mypages as $page ) {
              $content  = $page->post_content;
              if ( ! $content )
                continue;

                $property = get_field('property_category', $page->ID);
                $content  = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
                $location = get_field('google_map', $page->ID);
            ?>
              <li data-property-type="<?php echo strtolower($property); ?>"><a data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
          ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here's what the page layout currently looks like:
[Map Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IawTi.jpg)